# Android ScrollView is laggy when using with multiple ImageViews (Rendering Problem)

Tags: android, xml, mobile, rendering

I am trying to create a simple home page for my application. However, I have a performance issue on my home page when trying to scroll my page. Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong or what I can do better in order to have a smooth scroll? (My images sizes are around 100kb on average.) I have tried to minimize the sizes of my images, using a recycler view, decreasing the amount of the LinearLayouts that I used, using ConstraintLayout instead of LinearLayout but none of these worked for me. Thanks for your help!

Here is the screenshot of my home page:
[My Home Page Screenshot Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYxDb.png)

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F6F0E2"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Bilgiler alınamadı"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />


        <!-- SİPARİŞ VE BİLGİLER -->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <!-- TİTLE -->
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="SİPARİŞ VE BİLGİLER"
                android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <!-- CHECK-IN -->
                <TableRow>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="55dp"
                        android:layout_height="55dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/check" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                            android:text="Check-In"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            android:text="QR Kod Okut"
                            android:textColor="#949494"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:background="#c0c0c0" />

                <!-- MENÜ -->
                <TableRow>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="55dp"
                        android:layout_height="55dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/menu" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                            android:text="Menü"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            android:text="Görmek için tıklayınız"
                            android:textColor="#949494"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:background="#c0c0c0" />

                <!-- SİPARİŞLER -->
                <TableRow>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="55dp"
                        android:layout_height="55dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/siparisler" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                            android:text="Siparişler"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            android:text="Siparişlerinize göz atın"
                            android:textColor="#949494"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:background="#c0c0c0" />

                <!-- WC -->
                <TableRow>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="55dp"
                        android:layout_height="55dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/wc" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                            android:text="WC Bay - AQQQQ"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="12dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            android:text="WC Bayan - AQQQQQ"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="12dp" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:background="#c0c0c0" />

                <!-- RESTORAN -->
                <TableRow android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="55dp"
                        android:layout_height="55dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/rest" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                            android:text="Restoran - AQQQQ"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            android:text="Sıra Al - Ort: 31 dk"
                            android:textColor="#949494"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <!-- ÇAĞRI VE YARDIM -->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:background="#ffffff">

            <!-- TİTLE -->
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="ÇAĞRI VE YARDIM"
                android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <!-- GARSON ÇAĞIR -->
                <TableRow>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="55dp"
                        android:layout_height="55dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/waiter" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                            android:text="Garson Çağır"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:background="#c0c0c0" />

                <!-- HESAP İSTE -->
                <TableRow>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="55dp"
                        android:layout_height="55dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/wallet" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                            android:text="Hesap İste"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:background="#c0c0c0" />

                <!-- HALKLA İLİŞKİLER -->
                <TableRow>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="55dp"
                        android:layout_height="55dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/hr" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                            android:text="Halkla İlişkiler"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            android:text="Yardım İste"
                            android:textColor="#949494"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:background="#c0c0c0" />
            </TableLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <!-- ÇAĞRI VE YARDIM -->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:background="#ffffff">

            <!-- TİTLE -->
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="ÇAĞRI VE YARDIM"
                android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <!-- GARSON ÇAĞIR -->
                <TableRow>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="55dp"
                        android:layout_height="55dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/waiter" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                            android:text="Garson Çağır"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:background="#c0c0c0" />

                <!-- HESAP İSTE -->
                <TableRow>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="55dp"
                        android:layout_height="55dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/wallet" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                            android:text="Hesap İste"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:background="#c0c0c0" />

                <!-- HALKLA İLİŞKİLER -->
                <TableRow>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="55dp"
                        android:layout_height="55dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/hr" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                            android:text="Halkla İlişkiler"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            android:text="Yardım İste"
                            android:textColor="#949494"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:background="#c0c0c0" />
            </TableLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: There is no problem with your `xml` layout. You are likely using high quality image resources. So use light resources and your problem should be gone.

Comment: @Saj My images made on photoshop and the images are high quality but the size of the images are around 100kb-150kb. Not too heavy I guess.

Comment: Both file size and dimensions matter but dimensions have even more severe impact on application's performance. As a rule of thumb, if your image is going to fill the screen width, then a width of 300 pixels would be good. And if it is supposed to fill half the screen, 150 pixels would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Recyclerview instead of Scrollview. This way you will use much less resources.
So coding this way, each row in your table will be an element in Recyclerview.

Comment: I have already tried to used the RecyclerView instead of Scrollview. It was faster than the ScrollView but it wasn't smooth enough like a normal application.

Comment: Then you have to reduce the bitmap file sizes by compressing them to another format like jpg or have them in a lower resolution. For example if your Imageviews are 55*55 your bitmap doesn't need to have a higher resolution.